# Changing connection strings in an ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, web-config, connection-string

I tried to run a project from GitHub:
https://github.com/MarlabsInc/SocialGoal

It says "Open the web.config and change the connecting string "SocialGoalEntities" for working with your system."

```
<connectionStrings>
      <add name="SocialGoalEntities" connectionString="Data Source=.\;Initial Catalog=SocialGoal;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

What am I supposed to do in order to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means change the connection string according to your system.

For example,

```
<connectionString><add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="data source=Your data source; initial catalog=your db name;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /></connectionString>
```

You can replace DefaultConnection with any name you like, replace Your data source (your sql server instance name) and your db name according to your system.For more information about connection string please visit [connectionstrings.com](https://www.connectionstrings.com/)

Then enable migration if it is not already enabled for the projects from the package manager console using the following command:

> Enable-Migrations

Add a migration from package manager console using the following command:

> Add-Migration migrationName

Then update the database from package manager console using the following command:

> Update-Database

Answer (score 1):

I assume this project is build upon code first approach. You need to provide proper connection string which refers to your local system database and sql server. Then after you need to migrate Model using EF migration tool which will create tables in your database.